# jQuery animation callback problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nivo-slider

```
function thumb_wheel() {
    $("#slider .nivo-controlNav img").animate({left: '-600px'}, 14000, function(){  
        $(this).css({left:'0px'}, function(){
            thumb_wheel();
        });
    });
};
```

Basically, once the animation finishes, I would like it to reset "left" to 0px, and call itself again. I've tried formatting it different ways, using setInterval, etc... Checked Google, Stack, and #jQuery... and no matter what I try, it seems to 'hang' when I add the reset. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.css()` callback and just calling the two functions sequentially?

Comment: Well I just noticed I was missing a parenthesis, so I added that and now it calls back, but it doesn't run thumb_wheel(); again. Edit- And trying it sequentially didn't work @_@ Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: You could do a `while` loop. I'm not really sure what else to suggest, as that code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a working solution in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GjemU/

You had some syntax errors in your code as well as you tried to use a non-existing callback on `.css`

Comment: You beat me!  To add to this, the reason your posted code doesn't work is that `css` does not have a callback.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

the callback is being called in a different scope, so the `this` variable points to a different object than you think.
The solution is to a use closure:

```
function thumb_wheel() {
    var el = $("#slider .nivo-controlNav img");
    el.animate({left: '-600px'}, 14000, function(){  
         el.css({left:'0px'});
         thumb_wheel();
    });
};
```

Comment: I believe `this` was exactly what he thought it was and your code would now make `that` equal the window object.